# Meaning of the word "as" in the phrase "as from"

Tags: meaning

What is meaning if the word "as" in the phrase "as from." Would it make sense if I omit it? For example, "(As) from today, he is fired"

Comment: More context is needed. "As from" sounds irregular to me. In your example, you absolutely should delete it. You can say "as of today" but not "as from today."

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112770/understanding-as-of-as-at-and-as-from

Comment: I think you got it wrong. The actual expression is ***as of today***.

Comment: @mplungjan Oops. Well, I'm always glad to learn a new bit of BrE.

Answer (score 1):

**as from** (chiefly BrE) - used to indicate the time or date when something begins: *The new law takes effect as from* [=as of] *July 1. As from next Monday she’ll have a new secretary.*

**as of** is the preferred form in AmE:  * We shall be at our new address as of mid-June.*

Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary + [Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+from)

formal (in expressions of time) **from** • *fares on all routes will rise as from January 11*

Collins English Dictionary 8th Ed.

Comment: Please cite your source, otherwise it is plagiarism.